# Android Recyclerview section creation/customization/layout change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, sections

Is there a way to create a recyclerview with sections that a fully customizable? I have found [this](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) library for creating sections inside recyclerview and that part works fine. But what I want is to customize every section, e.g. set the background color of each one (not the items inside the section, but the section, the Items I can manipulate with different viewholders), and if possible change the layout (switch between horizontal scrolling and grid layout inside each section).

I want something like this:

[image]

I am wondering if there is some out of the box way to achive that (like on iOS)

Comment: There's [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) and [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) which should allow what you want.

Comment: Thank you, didnt know about them. They seem interesting

Comment: Tried them both out, but have the same problem like the library I wrote. You can style every item but you cant style the holder of all items. I ended up changing my design so I can use the "standard" tools provided by android (imo the effort is too high for such a trivial task to pursue it further)